# Excel formula to count rows meeting multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having trouble coming up with an excel formula to count how many times John S. had "Bid Wrong" and was "Over Hours".

The formula result would be = 3.

| Name | Result |
| --- | --- |
| John S. | Over Hours |
| John S. | Over Material |
| John S. | Bid Wrong |
| Tucker B. | Bid Right |
| John S. | Bid Wrong |

I feel like this should be easy to do and I'm just missing something. But it has me stumped.

Comment: Try looking at the [COUNTIFS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function and see how far you can get on your own with that. You may need two different formulas and add their result. You can also make one fancy formula but `=COUNTIFS(~)+COUNTIFS(~)` would be simpler to follow. Depending on what your data looks like and what other groupings you may care about, a pivot table may be another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many functions that you could use. One of them is `SUMPRODUCT`:

If you want where the result is either "bid wrong" or "over hours", use the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=C11)*((B2:B6="bid wrong")+(B2:B6="over hours")))
```

[image]